# ItemsControl.ItemsSource, binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf

This is pretty much my first attempt in data binding with WPF. When I run the program, nothing gets displayed although DataContext is set. The dummy mouse event handler checks the ItemsSource, but it is null.

What's wrong with the binding? Is there way to debug the string-related binding stuff, or is this always like walking across a minefield in WPF?

Remark: don't care about the wrong name "listBox1", I changed from ListBox to ItemsControl because I thought simpler is better for debugging.

**Code behind:**

```
namespace TestGraphDataBinding
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<RectangleModel> Rectangles = new ObservableCollection<RectangleModel>();

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            Rectangles.Add(new RectangleModel(0,0,1.0,0));
        }

        void whatsGoingOn(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Assert(listBox1.ItemsSource != null);
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="TestGraphDataBinding.Window1" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestGraphDataBinding"
    Title="TestGraphDataBinding"
    Height="500"
    Width="500">
    <ItemsControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}"
        x:Name="listBox1"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="whatsGoingOn">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="White"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate
                DataType="{x:Type local:RectangleModel}">
                <Rectangle
                    Width="10"
                    Height="10"
                    Fill="Azure">
                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TranslateTransform
                                X="{Binding X}"
                                Y="{Binding Y}" />
                            <ScaleTransform
                                ScaleX="{Binding Scale}"
                                ScaleY="{Binding Scale}" />
                            <RotateTransform
                                Angle="{Binding Angle}" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

**Model:**

```
namespace TestGraphDataBinding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of RectangleModel.
    /// </summary>
    public class RectangleModel
    {
        public double X {get; private set;}
        public double Y {get; private set;}
        public double Scale {get; private set;}
        public double Angle {get; private set;}

        public RectangleModel(double x, double y, double scale, double angle)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Scale = scale;
            Angle = angle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, the private setters of the RectangleModel properties seem to be redundant. If properties are only set in a constructor, a getter is sufficient. If the properties are supposed to be changed later, the class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: @Clemens: Is this C# version-specific? Because mine will complain without setters, at least without a backing field.

Comment: Oh, yes. This is a newer feature. Don't know the exact C# version though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF data binding only works with public properties. `Rectangles` must hence be a property, not a field:

```
public ObservableCollection<RectangleModel> Rectangles { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<RectangleModel>();
```

Comment: Interesting... didn't know this is so important. Is there a way to get the framework inform me about such precious details?

Comment: You should have got a data binding warning message in the Output Window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Wow. Lesson learned. Almost never used the output window since the good old c++ console application days.... ;-)